# How fire "mute" event on the peer in webRTC

Tags: firefox, webrtc

I have implemented webRtc connection using JS (Firefox v.112).
My peer successfully gets `unmute` event when it gets tracks from my computer.
But if my computer disables the track, which previously was sent to peer, using: `sentVideoTrack.enabled = false`, then peer does not receive `mute` event.
I don't call `removeTrack` - only set `enabled` field.
I have performed test with 2 browser windows  on localhost.
Receiving video on the peer is stopped - ok!, but should he receive `mute` event ?
If no, which event can the peer intercept while my computer is setting `track.enabled` to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the tracks `enabled` to false does not stop sending media, it only sends black frames (for video) or silence (for audio).

The common solution is to use the signaling channel to signal the fact that you muted to the other side.